# How to write a query using DATE data type in cassandra query language?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have created the table

```
create table testdates2(dates date primary key,ate text);

insert into testdates2(2018-04,'nov');
```

I am getting this error

> SyntaxException: line 1:23 no viable alternative at input '2018'
>   (insert into testdates2([2018]...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is `yyyy-mm-dd` meaning you have to always suplay a day as well. Here's an example using your schema that will insert a row for 1st April 2018. I picked a random value for the `ate` column.

```
cqlsh> insert into testdates2 (dates, ate) VALUES ('2018-04-01', 'Soup');
cqlsh> select * from testdates2;

 dates      | ate
------------+------
 2018-04-01 | Soup

(1 rows)
```

You can find more detailed documentation on using date values with Cassandra in [DataStax's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDateTimeFormats.html) on the subject.

**Edit** based on the comment regarding timestamp vs date.

`timestamp` has a higher resolution, it can point to the exact second an event occurred while `date` can point to the day an event occurred.

Let's say I want to know exactly what second that soup was eaten, I can use a timestamp type instead of the date type.

```
ALTER TABLE testdates2 ADD time_eaten timestamp;
insert into testdates2 (dates, ate, time_eaten) VALUES ('2018-04-01', 'Soup', 1522576800);
```

1522576800 and 2019-04-01 both represent 1st April 2018 but the timestamp also specifies the event occurred at 10 am.

Comment: May I know what is the datatype for DATE in cassandra? Is it just "date" or "timestamp"? whats the difference between "date" and "timestamp" ?

Comment: Both represent time but `timestamp` has a higher resolution, it can point to the exact second an event occurred while `date` can point to the day an event occurred. Which one you want to use depends on how accurate you wish to be.

Comment: How can we change the values from "null" to date? I have added create_date column to my existing table.Values are null.How can i change the value?

Comment: InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (2018-04-01) for "create_date" of type set<date>"           When I update there is a problem

Comment: I wish Cassandra had a builtin function to translate from epoch to DD-MM-YYY hh:mm:ss